# Obtaining data from one array based on data from a different array php

Tags: php, arrays

my basic array structures are as follows

```
$user_data = [
            [
                'user_id'           => '1',
                'user_name'         => 'numpty',
                'email'             => 'john@somewhere.com',
                'first_name'        => 'John',
                'last_name'         => 'Smith'
            ],
            [
                'user_id'           => '2',
                'user_name'         => 'fairy52',
                'email'             => 'natasha@legs.com',
                'first_name'        => 'Natasha',
                'last_name'         => 'Jones'
            ],
            [
                'user_id'           => '3',
                'user_name'         => 'angie_turmoil',
                'email'             => 'ange@nightmare.com',
                'first_name'        => 'Angela',
                'last_name'         => 'Swift'
            ],
            [
                'user_id'           => '4',
                'user_name'         => 'dastardly_dan',
                'email'             => 'daniel@aol.com',
                'first_name'        => 'Daniel',
                'last_name'         => 'McNash'
            ],
            [
                'user_id'           => '5',
                'user_name'         => 'horse',
                'email'             => 'fred@features.com',
                'first_name'        => 'Frederick',
                'last_name'         => 'Walsh'
            ]
        ];

$user_followers = [
                    [
                        'user_id'   => '1',
                        'followers' => ['3', '4', '5']
                    ],
                    [
                        'user_id'   => '2',
                        'followers' => ['1', '5']
                    ],
                    [
                        'user_id'   => '3',
                        'followers' => ['1', '5', '4']
                    ],
                    [
                        'user_id'   => '4',
                        'followers' => ['3', '1', '5']
                    ],
                    [
                        'user_id'   => '5',
                        'followers' => ['1', '2', '4']
                    ],
                ];
```

What I need to do is for each `$user_data` return the followers name based on the `user_id` therefore for the first record in `$user_data` I need to return the names

```
angie_turmoil
dastardly_dan
horse
```

I understand that this is not a conventional way of storing data, but it is a prototype project for learning OOP PHP and I am not required to use a database for the data storage.

Comment: The code in this question <> learning OOP. How about you start with a `User` class that has self referential properties `follows` and `followers`?

Comment: Any change you'd accept to change the array structure?

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond I think this is becoming a logical option

Comment: @Sideshow i was also considering performance.

Answer (score 0):

As your data currently constructed, if you want to try a simple foreach, you could do something like this. Consider this example:

```
$data = array();
foreach($user_followers as $index => $element) {
    $current_user = $element['user_id']; // get the current user in iteration
    $followers = $element['followers']; // get his/her followers
    foreach($followers as $f_user_id) {
        foreach($user_data as $key => $value) { // search the current user followers inside the user_data
            if($value['user_id'] == $f_user_id) {
                $data[$current_user]['follower_names'][] = $value['user_name'];
            }
        }
    }

}

print_r($data);
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [follower_names] => Array
        (
            [0] => angie_turmoil
            [1] => dastardly_dan
            [2] => horse
        )

    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [follower_names] => Array
        (
            [0] => numpty
            [1] => horse
        )

    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [follower_names] => Array
        (
            [0] => numpty
            [1] => horse
            [2] => dastardly_dan
        )

    )

// and so on.
```

> *Note: They array keys are the user_id, the values inside are their followers.*

Answer (score 0):

This is a little wild, but hey, it works:

```
$list = array();    
foreach ($user_data as $user) 
    foreach ($user_followers as $followers) 
        if ($followers['user_id']==$user['user_id'])
            foreach ($followers['followers'] as $f_id)
                foreach ($user_data as $user2)
                    if ($user2['user_id']==$f_id)
                        $list[$user['user_name']][] = $user2['user_name'];

print_r($list);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [numpty] => Array
        (
            [0] => angie_turmoil
            [1] => dastardly_dan
            [2] => horse
        )

    [fairy52] => Array
        (
            [0] => numpty
            [1] => horse
        )

    [angie_turmoil] => Array
        (
            [0] => numpty
            [1] => horse
            [2] => dastardly_dan
        )

    [dastardly_dan] => Array
        (
            [0] => angie_turmoil
            [1] => numpty
            [2] => horse
        )

    [horse] => Array
        (
            [0] => numpty
            [1] => fairy52
            [2] => dastardly_dan
        )
)
```